# B2C Change sign in name/email address difficulty trying to tie up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the custom starterpack policies from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa

I'm trying to configure the change of email address using https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/change-sign-in-name, and even though I've uploaded these policies with the tenant ID all correctly set, etc. Struggling to understand how to trigger this - apart from uploading the 2 files in this repo, do I need to do anything in the files from the startpack?

When I click on the "change email" button on the UI, I enter a new email address, the UI then expects a verification code the should be sent to the new email address, but no email ever arrives. I've checked the junk mail and tried different other email addresses too with no luck. I've added App Insights logging to the `RelyingParty`, but even though it shows some logs related to B2C, nothing shows up related to the change signin name policy.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"change email" button?

If you watch the video, there isn't one.

You need to run the B2C_1A_Demo_ChangeSignInName policy from the portal e.g.
'Run Now".